# Pandas Dataframe add column based on counts of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe containing sports match information:

```
tournament    playerA    playerB
1             A          B 
1             C          B
1             D          A
2             A          B
2             A          C
2             A          D
```

I now want to add a new column (or create a new dataframe; whatever is easier to accomplish) containing information on how many players participated *per* tournament. *Players participated* is the set (no duplicates) of *playerA* and *playerB* columns.

If a new column is added, the new dataframe should look like this (tournament 1 has 4 players participating, i.e., *A, B, C, and D*; tournament two has 3 players participating, i.e., *A, B, and C*):

```
tournament    playerA    playerB    players_sum
1             A          B          4
1             C          B          4
1             D          A          4
2             A          B          3
2             A          C          3
```

If it's easier to create a new dataframe it could/should look like this:

```
tournament    players_sum
1             4
2             3
```

What I tried until now: I tried a `groupby()` and then `apply()` or `transform()` however I dont know how to merge the information of two columns (*playerA* and *playerB*).

Thanks, your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by creating a dictionary for the `unique()` tournament and player values and then mapping that to the new column.

```
tourneys = df['tournament'].unique()
player_dict = {}
for event in tourneys:
    ndf = df[df['tournament'] == event].copy()
    player_dict[event] = len(ndf['playerA'].append(ndf['playerB']).unique())

df['player_sum'] = df['tournament'].map(player_dict)
```

df

```
  playerA playerB  tournament  player_sum
0       A       B           1           4
1       C       B           1           4
2       D       A           1           4
3       A       B           2           3
4       A       C           2           3
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, in parallel, I also found a solution, I want to post it here:

```
def myfunc(group):
    w_set = set(group['playerA'])
    l_set = set(group['playerB'])
    group['player_sum'] = len(w_set.union(l_set))
    return group

df = df.reset_index().groupby('tournament').apply(myfunc)
```